# Class Class Member Initialization with Non-default Ctor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, definition

I have a confusion about a class member declaration which is a class.

In the following example when I declare "A m_a;" what is happening? From what I understand the ctor its not called yet. Still I have trouble understand what is wrong in my last code line (B ctor implementation)?

example I have two classes:

```
class A{
   A(int a);
   ...
};

class B{
  B(int b);
  A m_a;
  ...
};
```

this is what I wish to do:

```
B::B(int b): m_a(b){}
```

I get multiple errors:

```
candidate expects 1 arguments, 0 provided
candidate: constexpr 
only constructors take member initializers
...
```

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, make sure the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the errors actually match. Or rather, that the errors come from the MCVE that you show. In this case it's somewhat trivial to *guess* about the problem, but it might not always be that easy.

Comment: After your edit, it's no longer trivial to guess, and you *really* need to make sure the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you show is what causes the error you show. And remember, don't edit or modify the errors you show, do a straight (and full and complete) copy-paste from the build-log.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is to use the name of the member variable, not its type. Type is used for base classes only.

```
B::B(int b): m_a(b){}
```

Had `B` been defined as:

```
class B : public A {
  B(int b);
};
```

Use of

```
B::B(int b): A(b){}
```

would be the correct syntax.

Comment: sorry I it's a mistake in my writing I am editing the post.

Comment: @NoaYehezkel, your updated code should work. The problem is elsewhere. Please post a [mcve]. The missing `;` in the class definitions is a problem.

Comment: @NoaYehezkel If it was something trivial or a typo, then delete it yourself. Otherwise, if it's something that other could learn from, then post an answer yourself and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If to place at least semicolons that end the class definitions and use correct access specifiers and define correctly the constractor of the class B then the code will compile.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
public: 
   A(int a) : x( a ) {}
private:   
   int x;
};

class B{
public: 
  B(int b);
private:  
  A m_a;
};

B::B(int b): m_a(b){}

int main() 
{
    A a( 10 );
    B b( 10 );

    return 0;
}
```